User purposefully deleting question after an answer has been provided
If I remember correctly, once there is an answer given to a post, the post cannot be deleted by the author. I experienced this in some other SE sites where if the author tries to delete a question, the system would prevent saying You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it..
However, recently this question has been asked How to interpret defect formation energy diagram? and then deleted by the author after I wrote an answer here on MMSE. Writing an answer requires spending some time and thus I think it is reasonable to expect that a post should not be possible to delete after providing an answer.
Is there a time constraint after which deletion is restricted, or is MMSE yet to implement the feature? In any case, I am expecting inputs from other users about steps that can be taken to prevent such instances and which would value our effort and time.

I agree with Camps that surrounding commentary had become a distraction. However, the user has deleted their account and I have purged the comments, so I think question and answer can stand. This allows the prior user to disassociate themselves from the question while still allowing the answer you put a lot of time into to remain in place.

I really think that there were many (bad) issues with that question. Bad editions, harassment, etc. All that happening with a new user!
If the OP didn't feel well with all the comments, it is his/her right to delete the questions (and also close his/her account at MSSE). It is the same thing that happens when a user closes his account: all the earned credits are removed.

If this is the MMSE policy, I am okay with it. This specific question might be a bad example as it seems my edit made him angry, and instead of defending that action, I could have acted otherwise. But in general I would like this feature where if there is already an answer, the OP will not have the sole authority to delete the post


A user cannot delete a question if there is an answer with a positive score. The SE system will not allow the asker to delete the question.

Users do not have a legal right to permanently delete their own questions or answers, since they have provided SE (and the rest of the world) with the Creative Commons license to publish the work, which is why Codidact re-publishes all questions and answers on some SE sites without the authors even knowing about it.

Users can delete their own posts if the community agrees with the deletion but these posts can easily be un-deleted when the community chooses to do that.

In your case, what the asker did is referred on SE as "self-vandalism".

Sorry that this happened to you and that people were unable to act more quickly. I did vote to un-delete the question, and flagged it for a quicker un-deletion, but I am not a diamond moderator so I couldn't solve the problem without help from others.


